# Core Url Rewrite bug in Magento 1.8?

Tags: magento-1.8, url-rewrite

I remember there was a bug in Magento 1.7 and EE 1.12 which generated URL writes each time a category was saved. We noticed this when clients started seeing millions of URL rewrites. There was a patch for EE1.12 which also worked for 1.7. Do you know if this bug was fixed in 1.8? The reason I ask is I have a client who started at 1.3 and is now on 1.8 and their urls are at 200,000 (6700 SKU's 300 categories)

The URLS have grown by 20,000 in the past week along.

Comment: I did find the patch - SUPEE-389_EE_1.12.0.2_v1.patch -  I will try it and report back

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/17553/142). Would be really interesting to know if the fix does the same or something else?

Comment: Version 2 from Piotre K Kaminski's Github [PATCH_SUPEE-389_EE_1.12.0.2_v2.sh](https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/c348538ca91ba35773be)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The patch for EE 1.12 work to resolve the re-write problems

SUPEE-389_EE_1.12.0.2_v1.patch

Here is the code from Github
    #!/bin/bash
    # Patch apllying tool template
    # v0.1.2
    # (c) Copyright 2013. Magento Inc.
    #
    # DO NOT CHANGE ANY LINE IN THIS FILE.

```
# 1. Check required system tools
_check_installed_tools() {
    local missed=""

    until [ -z "$1" ]; do
        type -t $1 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
        if (( $? != 0 )); then
            missed="$missed $1"
        fi
        shift
    done

    echo $missed
}

REQUIRED_UTILS='sed patch'
MISSED_REQUIRED_TOOLS=`_check_installed_tools $REQUIRED_UTILS`
if (( `echo $MISSED_REQUIRED_TOOLS | wc -w` > 0 ));
then
    echo -e "Error! Some required system tools, that are utilized in this sh script, are not installed:\nTool(s) \"$MISSED_REQUIRED_TOOLS\" is(are) missed, please install it(them)."
    exit 1
fi

# 2. Determine bin path for system tools
CAT_BIN=`which cat`
PATCH_BIN=`which patch`
SED_BIN=`which sed`
PWD_BIN=`which pwd`
BASENAME_BIN=`which basename`

BASE_NAME=`$BASENAME_BIN "$0"`

# 3. Help menu
if [ "$1" = "-?" -o "$1" = "-h" -o "$1" = "--help" ]
then
    $CAT_BIN << EOFH
Usage: sh $BASE_NAME [--help] [-R|--revert] [--list]
Apply embedded patch.

-R, --revert    Revert previously applied embedded patch
--list          Show list of applied patches
--help          Show this help message
EOFH
    exit 0
fi

# 4. Get "revert" flag and "list applied patches" flag
REVERT_FLAG=
SHOW_APPLIED_LIST=0
if [ "$1" = "-R" -o "$1" = "--revert" ]
then
    REVERT_FLAG=-R
fi
if [ "$1" = "--list" ]
then
    SHOW_APPLIED_LIST=1
fi

# 5. File pathes
CURRENT_DIR=`$PWD_BIN`/
APP_ETC_DIR=`echo "$CURRENT_DIR""app/etc/"`
APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE=`echo "$APP_ETC_DIR""applied.patches.list"`

# 6. Show applied patches list if requested
if [ "$SHOW_APPLIED_LIST" -eq 1 ] ; then
    echo -e "Applied/reverted patches list:"
    if [ -e "$APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE" ]
    then
        if [ ! -r "$APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE" ]
        then
            echo "ERROR: \"$APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE\" must be readable so applied patches list can be shown."
            exit 1
        else
            $SED_BIN -n "/SUP-\|SUPEE-/p" $APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE
        fi
    else
        echo "<empty>"
    fi
    exit 0
fi

# 7. Check applied patches track file and its directory
_check_files() {
    if [ ! -e "$APP_ETC_DIR" ]
    then
        echo "ERROR: \"$APP_ETC_DIR\" must exist for proper tool work."
        exit 1
    fi

    if [ ! -w "$APP_ETC_DIR" ]
    then
        echo "ERROR: \"$APP_ETC_DIR\" must be writeable for proper tool work."
        exit 1
    fi

    if [ -e "$APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE" ]
    then
        if [ ! -w "$APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE" ]
        then
            echo "ERROR: \"$APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE\" must be writeable for proper tool work."
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
}

_check_files

# 8. Apply/revert patch
# Note: there is no need to check files permissions for files to be patched.
# "patch" tool will not modify any file if there is not enough permissions for all files to be modified.
# Get start points for additional information and patch data
SKIP_LINES=$((`$SED_BIN -n "/^__PATCHFILE_FOLLOWS__$/=" "$CURRENT_DIR""$BASE_NAME"` + 1))
ADDITIONAL_INFO_LINE=$(($SKIP_LINES - 3))p

_apply_revert_patch() {
    DRY_RUN_FLAG=
    if [ "$1" = "dry-run" ]
    then
        DRY_RUN_FLAG=" --dry-run"
        echo "Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully..."
    fi
    PATCH_APPLY_REVERT_RESULT=`$SED_BIN -e '1,/^__PATCHFILE_FOLLOWS__$/d' "$CURRENT_DIR""$BASE_NAME" | $PATCH_BIN $DRY_RUN_FLAG $REVERT_FLAG -p0`
    PATCH_APPLY_REVERT_STATUS=$?
    if [ $PATCH_APPLY_REVERT_STATUS -eq 1 ] ; then
        echo -e "ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.\n\n$PATCH_APPLY_REVERT_RESULT"
        exit 1
    fi
    if [ $PATCH_APPLY_REVERT_STATUS -eq 2 ] ; then
        echo -e "ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully."
        exit 2
    fi
}

REVERTED_PATCH_MARK=
if [ -n "$REVERT_FLAG" ]
then
    REVERTED_PATCH_MARK=" | REVERTED"
fi

_apply_revert_patch dry-run
_apply_revert_patch

# 9. Track patch applying result
echo "Patch was applied/reverted successfully."
ADDITIONAL_INFO=`$SED_BIN -n ""$ADDITIONAL_INFO_LINE"" "$CURRENT_DIR""$BASE_NAME"`
APPLIED_REVERTED_ON_DATE=`date -u +"%F %T UTC"`
APPLIED_REVERTED_PATCH_INFO=`echo -n "$APPLIED_REVERTED_ON_DATE"" | ""$ADDITIONAL_INFO""$REVERTED_PATCH_MARK"`
echo -e "$APPLIED_REVERTED_PATCH_INFO\n$PATCH_APPLY_REVERT_RESULT\n\n" >> "$APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE"

exit 0


SUPEE-389 | EE_1.12.0.2 | v1 | 53c8ca52583358953b143aaa1a78cf409e8dd846 | Thu Jun 20 10:36:39 2013 +0300 | v1.12.0.2..HEAD

__PATCHFILE_FOLLOWS__
diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php
index fa55fc5..a755b46 100644
--- app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php
@@ -609,6 +609,23 @@ class Mage_Catalog_Model_Url
      */
     public function getUnusedPath($storeId, $requestPath, $idPath)
     {
+        $urlKey = '';
+        return $this->getUnusedPathByUrlkey($storeId, $requestPath, $idPath, $urlKey);
+    }
+
+    /**
+     * Get requestPath that was not used yet.
+     *
+     * Will try to get unique path by adding -1 -2 etc. between url_key and optional url_suffix
+     *
+     * @param int $storeId
+     * @param string $requestPath
+     * @param string $idPath
+     * @param string $urlKey
+     * @return string
+     */
+    public function getUnusedPathByUrlkey($storeId, $requestPath, $idPath, $urlKey = '')
+    {
         if (strpos($idPath, 'product') !== false) {
             $suffix = $this->getProductUrlSuffix($storeId);
         } else {
@@ -645,21 +662,22 @@ class Mage_Catalog_Model_Url
             }
             // match request_url abcdef1234(-12)(.html) pattern
             $match = array();
-            $regularExpression = '#^([0-9a-z/-]+?)(-([0-9]+))?('.preg_quote($suffix).')?$#i';
+            $regularExpression = '#(?P<prefix>(.*/)?' . preg_quote($urlKey) . ')(-(?P<increment>[0-9]+))?(?P<suffix>'
+                . preg_quote($suffix) . ')?$#i';
             if (!preg_match($regularExpression, $requestPath, $match)) {
-                return $this->getUnusedPath($storeId, '-', $idPath);
+                return $this->getUnusedPathByUrlkey($storeId, '-', $idPath, $urlKey);
             }
-            $match[1] = $match[1] . '-';
-            $match[4] = isset($match[4]) ? $match[4] : '';
+            $match['prefix'] = $match['prefix'] . '-';
+            $match['suffix'] = isset($match['suffix']) ? $match['suffix'] : '';

             $lastRequestPath = $this->getResource()
-                ->getLastUsedRewriteRequestIncrement($match[1], $match[4], $storeId);
+                ->getLastUsedRewriteRequestIncrement($match['prefix'], $match['suffix'], $storeId);
             if ($lastRequestPath) {
-                $match[3] = $lastRequestPath;
+                $match['increment'] = $lastRequestPath;
             }
-            return $match[1]
-                . (isset($match[3]) ? ($match[3]+1) : '1')
-                . $match[4];
+            return $match['prefix']
+                . (isset($match['increment']) ? ($match['increment']+1) : '1')
+                . $match['suffix'];
         }
         else {
             return $requestPath;
@@ -699,7 +717,7 @@ class Mage_Catalog_Model_Url
     {
         $storeId = $category->getStoreId();
         $idPath  = $this->generatePath('id', null, $category);
-        $suffix  = $this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($storeId);
+        $categoryUrlSuffix = $this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($storeId);

         if (isset($this->_rewrites[$idPath])) {
             $this->_rewrite = $this->_rewrites[$idPath];
@@ -713,27 +731,27 @@ class Mage_Catalog_Model_Url
             $urlKey = $this->getCategoryModel()->formatUrlKey($category->getUrlKey());
         }

-        $categoryUrlSuffix = $this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($category->getStoreId());
         if (null === $parentPath) {
             $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
         }
         elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
             $parentPath = '';
         }
-        $parentPath = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlPath($parentPath,
-                                                                           true, $category->getStoreId());
+        $parentPath = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlPath($parentPath, true, $storeId);

-        $requestPath = $parentPath . $urlKey . $categoryUrlSuffix;
-        if (isset($existingRequestPath) && $existingRequestPath == $requestPath . $suffix) {
+        $requestPath = $parentPath . $urlKey;
+        $regexp = '/^' . preg_quote($requestPath, '/') . '(\-[0-9]+)?' . preg_quote($categoryUrlSuffix, '/') . '$/i';
+        if (isset($existingRequestPath) && preg_match($regexp, $existingRequestPath)) {
             return $existingRequestPath;
         }

-        if ($this->_deleteOldTargetPath($requestPath, $idPath, $storeId)) {
+        $fullPath = $requestPath . $categoryUrlSuffix;
+        if ($this->_deleteOldTargetPath($fullPath, $idPath, $storeId)) {
             return $requestPath;
         }

-        return $this->getUnusedPath($category->getStoreId(), $requestPath,
-                                    $this->generatePath('id', null, $category)
+        return $this->getUnusedPathByUrlkey($storeId, $fullPath,
+            $this->generatePath('id', null, $category), $urlKey
         );
     }

@@ -798,7 +816,8 @@ class Mage_Catalog_Model_Url
             $this->_rewrite = $this->_rewrites[$idPath];
             $existingRequestPath = $this->_rewrites[$idPath]->getRequestPath();

-            if ($existingRequestPath == $requestPath . $suffix) {
+            $regexp = '/^' . preg_quote($requestPath, '/') . '(\-[0-9]+)?' . preg_quote($suffix, '/') . '$/i';
+            if (preg_match($regexp, $existingRequestPath)) {
                 return $existingRequestPath;
             }

@@ -836,7 +855,7 @@ class Mage_Catalog_Model_Url
         /**
          * Use unique path generator
          */
-        return $this->getUnusedPath($storeId, $requestPath.$suffix, $idPath);
+        return $this->getUnusedPathByUrlkey($storeId, $requestPath.$suffix, $idPath, $urlKey);
     }

     /**
@@ -891,8 +910,8 @@ class Mage_Catalog_Model_Url
                 $parentPath = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlPath($parentPath,
                     true, $category->getStoreId());

-                return $this->getUnusedPath($category->getStoreId(), $parentPath . $urlKey . $categoryUrlSuffix,
-                    $this->generatePath('id', null, $category)
+                return $this->getUnusedPathByUrlkey($category->getStoreId(), $parentPath . $urlKey . $categoryUrlSuffix,
+                    $this->generatePath('id', null, $category), $urlKey
                 );
             }

@@ -913,14 +932,14 @@ class Mage_Catalog_Model_Url
                 $this->_addCategoryUrlPath($category);
                 $categoryUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlPath($category->getUrlPath(),
                     false, $category->getStoreId());
-                return $this->getUnusedPath($category->getStoreId(), $categoryUrl . '/' . $urlKey . $productUrlSuffix,
-                    $this->generatePath('id', $product, $category)
+                return $this->getUnusedPathByUrlkey($category->getStoreId(), $categoryUrl . '/' . $urlKey . $productUrlSuffix,
+                    $this->generatePath('id', $product, $category), $urlKey
                 );
             }

             // for product only
-            return $this->getUnusedPath($category->getStoreId(), $urlKey . $productUrlSuffix,
-                $this->generatePath('id', $product)
+            return $this->getUnusedPathByUrlkey($category->getStoreId(), $urlKey . $productUrlSuffix,
+                $this->generatePath('id', $product), $urlKey
             );
         }
```

Comment: Where is that available from? The original Bug Tracking system that would provide the download links has eBayVaporated.

Comment: This is a EE patch :( - It is not available to community

Comment: Good news: It is available on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/c348538ca91ba35773be)! If you use it with CE make sure to test it properly, because it has been developed for EE.

Comment: Thanks, noted also that is Ver 2 of the patch. Appreciated as the next step in our upgrade path probably is 1.8 until I've grown trusting enough of 1.9 to go there.

Comment: @brentwpeterson - thank you for posting that here. I am starting to severely not trust the Magento website and forums to stay in existence. Things keep getting moved or upgraded out of existence over there and I'm not really that trusting either that they're going to maintain the forums or actually activate them for posting in the future. I have been following up on old answers where I linked to the Magento website and am transferring the info here just for that reason.