# Product URL rewrite not working

Tags: magento-enterprise, url-rewrite

Hi I have a product in magento and it was deleted via api call.
When I try to check the product detail page, the page was not found. I try to put the -1 on the url key, eg: small-business-premium-1 the product detail page can be seen.

Comment: Could you please more descriptive on this

Answer (score 0):

Alyssa.

It is a magento feature.`Magento is save product rewrite url to Url rewrite table.`In your Url rewrite `table magento is small-business-premium url already exits`,so magento is `prevent to  create url small-business-premium` thus magento `create url with append with a numeric value` because of `url key value() already exit Enterprise_UrlRewrite table`

**Edit:**

`delete`  small-business-premium from `Url rewrite Select` and  then save your product w with url key `small business premium`.

See more:
[why magento product url duplicating](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1565/why-magento-product-url-duplicating)

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee113-later-release-notes

Comment: so what should I do with this?

Comment: Delete this url from rewrite table.a