# Google WebMaster Tool Reports Odd Duplicated Meta Tags

Tags: google-analytics

I have a doubt that someone more experience might be able to help me.

Google Webmaster Tool has advised me about duplicated tags and contents in the website I work for. However, when I see the pages related to the duplication they actually are the same URL but with inexistent or odd ends like those:

**Pages with duplicate meta descriptions**

> ANTHONY MEN'S FACIAL MOISTURISER, lowest price guaranteed, hassle
>       free returns.

1. www.xxxxxxxx.com.au/anthony-all-purpose-facial-moisturiser-70g-16573.html
2. www.xxxxxxxx.com.au/anthony-all-purpose-facial-moisturiser-70g-16591.html
3. www.xxxxxxxx.com.au/anthony-all-purpose-facial-moisturiser-70g-16595.html
4. www.xxxxxxxx.com.au/anthony-all-purpose-facial-moisturiser-70g-16615.html

**The actual URL is**

1. www.xxxxxxxx.com.au/anthony-all-purpose-facial-moisturiser-70g-1.html

**My question is:**

1. Why do those odd number come in the end of the URLs making duplicated content in Google Webmaster Tool?

   Also we have URLs like that `www.xxxxxxxx.com.au/home-gifts-c-959/gifts-for-him/0` with `"/0"` in the end of it that is being reported by WMT. Do you know why this is happening in Magento?

Comment: Which version of Magento?

Comment: basically it started on 1.12 and we still have it on 1.14. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is due to a patched bug in Magento core. Ref https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/2818/5 and check your product data; I'm assuming this is a product which has a connection with a configurable product or is itself a configurable product? If so, check that https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/34781/5 might resolve your problem.